# How can I use my search bar with google custom search?

Tags: javascript, html, search, google-search, google-custom-search

This is my html code for the form :

```
<form action="#" class="searh-holder">
    <input name="se" id="se" type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search.." value="" />
    <button class="search-submit" id="submit_btn"><i class="fa fa-search transition"></i></button>
</form>
```

And this is Google custom search script for results only :

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '013571851987533538767:dc4iymzquf8';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

I have no idea about how to make my search bar display Google custom search results. How can I get them work together? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in that input.

After a while that the user press a key, do the search in google and show the results opening into the autocomplete.